# Entropy of Sum vs Difference of Random Variable

Tags: probability, entropy

I am looking for a proof of the following fact

Let $X$ and$ X'$ be i.i.d on $\{0,1,2\}$ (not necessarily uniform). Prove that

$$H((X + X') \mod3) \leq H((X - X') \mod3)$$

where $H()$ is the standard Shannon entropy.

A short (or long) proof or any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: As Tom Lin points out (+1), this is not true.  What is true is that the inequality universally holds for the *conditional* random variables $X\pm X^\prime \mod 3 | X\pm X^\prime \ne 0$.

Comment: I had actually made a mistake in writing the inequality unfortunately. Does this direction hold?

Comment: Yes, the inequality is now correct. (+1)

Comment: Can you give me a proof of it?

Answer (score 3):

I found this suprisingly hard to prove, because the expressions for the entropies are messy.  One successful idea is to modify the distribution in a way that (a) fixes the entropy of $X-X^\prime$ while (b) increasing the entropy of $X+X^\prime$ (where the sum and difference will always be taken modulo $3$).   In this fashion the distribution of $X+X^\prime$ can be made the same as that of $X-X^\prime$, implying the *original* entropy of $X+X^\prime$ was no greater than that of $X-X^\prime$.

---

Let us designate the distribution of any random variable $X$ attaining the values $0,1,2$ by the vector of its probabilities $(\Pr(X=0), \Pr(X=1), \Pr(X=2))$. Letting the common distribution of $X$ and $X^\prime$ be $(p,q,r)$, which I will write $X\sim (p,q,r)$, we may directly compute that

$$X+X^\prime \sim (p^2 + 2qr, r^2 + 2pq, q^2 + 2pr)$$

and

$$X-X^\prime \sim (p^2+q^2+r^2, pr + qp + rq, pq + qr + rp).$$

Note that the last two coefficients are equal and observe that the value of the first (different) coefficient $t = p^2 + q^2 + r^2$ must lie between $1/3$ and $1$.  Thus we may alternatively parameterize the distribution of the difference in terms of $t$ as

$$X-X^\prime \sim \left(t, \frac{1-t}{2}, \frac{1-t}{2}\right)$$

for $t\in [1/3,1]$.

Now fix $t$ and adjust $(p,q,r)$ to make the entropy of $X+X^\prime$ as large as possible (so that the entropy of $X-X^\prime$ remains the same).  That is, modify $p, q, r$ without changing the equalities

$$t = p^2 + q^2 + r^2;\quad p+q+r=1.$$

If we temporarily fix one of the coefficients of $X+X^\prime$ then the entropy (which is proportional to the entropy of the random variable $X+X^\prime$ conditioned on not being equal to the corresponding value) increases as the remaining two coefficients move closer together; therefore, we may as well assume this has been done as much as possible and that two of the coefficients are actually *equal.*  This can be accomplished within the foregoing restrctictions by setting

$$p=\frac{1}{3}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{6t-2}\right);\quad q=r=\frac{1}{3}\left(1\mp \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{6t-2}\right).$$

In so doing we will have *increased* the entropy of $X+X^\prime$ while fixing the entropy of $X-X^\prime$.  However, as a result the distributions of $X+X^\prime$ and $X-X^\prime$ have become the same (that's an easy calculation based on these formulas for $p,q,$ and $r$) and so the resulting entropy is the same as that of $X-X^\prime$, *QED*.